# MVC base model properties set default values for new record creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a base model that has some common properties for several different forms.

```
public class BaseForm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SubId { get; set; }
    ...several more common properties...
}
```

I then have more specific models for the individual forms.

```
public class InfoForm : BaseForm
{
    public string Information { get; set; }
    public string Commands { get; set; }
}

public class WhatForm: BaseForm
{
    public string WhatHappens { get; set; }
    public string Behavior { get; set; }
}
```

Now when updating these models everything works great as the BaseForm.Id and BaseForm.SubId are populated by the existing record.

My lack of knowledge comes when creating a NEW record. The BaseForm.Id and BaseForm.SubId are predictable but different for each form.

For InfoForm they would be

```
Record one..
BaseForm.Id = 1 
BaseForm.SubId = 1

Record two..
BaseForm.Id = 2
BaseForm.SubId = 1

Record three..
BaseForm.Id = 3
BaseForm.SubId = 1

//Since Id is auto increment I assume it can be left blank for db
```

and WhatForm they would be

```
Record one..
BaseForm.Id = 1 
BaseForm.SubId = 2

Record two..
BaseForm.Id = 2
BaseForm.SubId = 2

Record three..
BaseForm.Id = 3
BaseForm.SubId = 2

//Since Id is auto increment I assume it can be left blank for db
```

I was aiming to have a single controller action and every form points to it but if I have to have a different controller action to set specific values to id and subid then so be it.

So my question is there a way to pre-populate these values or do I have to do it in the controller action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the constructor of your subclasses:

```
public class InfoForm : BaseForm
{
    public InfoForm()
    {
        SubId = 1;
    }

    ...
}
```

And, yes, you shouldn't mess with `Id`. Entity Framework will back-fill it with the auto id from the database, after saving.